# Lyx Shortcut Math Function Sign (e.g. accepts item in A returns item in B)

Tags: math-mode, macros, lyx, shortcut

I am using Lyx.
I would like to know if there is an equivalent to the following"from-to" sign:[image: rom A]

I've used _ and ^ but I believe there is a better way for it.

Comment: `{}^AB` would be the usual way

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using LyX, so, unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: You must be able to type mathematics somehow in lyx. If you can enter `$x^2$` then you must be able to enter `${}^AB$` surely????

Answer (score 0):

To obtain an equivalent of `${}^AB$` in LyX, you can

1. start an empty math mode box,
2. type `^` to enter superscript and enter the `A`,
3. press space to exit the superscript,
4. enter the `B` immediately after the superscript.

Checking `View > Source Pane`, the above produces `$^{A}B$`, which compiles as `${}^AB$`.

If it is something you need to insert many times, then create a keyboard shortcut: Go to `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts > New` and as function use `math-insert ^{A}B`.